# SVG image is not cropped in IE9

Tags: html, cross-browser, svg

The following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Test.</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <div style="border: solid 1px black; height:100px; width:100px">
            <svg height="100" width="100" viewbox="00 0 100 100">
                <path id="map1" d="M210 10 L90 10 L90 90 " fill="red"/>
            </svg>
        </div>
</html>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HRsvX/

In Chrome and FF4 displays div with border and part of image that is INSIDE of SVG-object. Everything outside of the svg is not drawn.

IE9 displays WHOLE SVG-image. Is it a feature or a bug? Is there any way to cut the 'outbounding' part of image?

Does Raphael framework handle such case correctly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Edit:** In light of my [new understanding of the spec](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10077264/191837), I must correct myself below.

The default style required by the spec for elements in the svg namespace is:

```
svg, symbol, image, marker, pattern, foreignObject { overflow: hidden }
svg { width:attr(width); height:attr(height) }
```

per http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#UAStyleSheet

So, if you want IE9 to conform you can use:

```
svg:not(:root) { overflow: hidden; }
```

As suggested [here](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-svg-wg/2008JulSep/0347.html) and [here](http://html5boilerplate.com/html5boilerplate-site/built/en_US/docs/css/#embedded-content).

The following is true if the default `overflow: hidden` is overridden:

According to the [SVG Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#InitialClippingPath), SVG handles `overflow` like any other element when contained within a document that is using CSS. Items inside of the element overflow unless `overflow: hidden` or `overflow:scroll` if they exceed the size of the parent.

In your example, I see it as the `path` exceeds the `viewbox` defined on the `svg` element. Since the default `overflow` is `visible`, the path will "bleed" beyond the `svg` element's boundries. Additionally, it bleeds beyond the `svg` element's parent boundries, etc.

Comment: BTW, IE10 experiences this bug, too.

Comment: you have just saved me hours with this answer. For anyone else having this issue with gwt and the lib-gwt-svg library, you can just include svg {overflow:hidden;} in your css file.

Comment: kevin, does this mean that the '(:not)' part is extraneous?

Comment: @Ringo good question, I just pasted as other browsers had implemented it at the time. Looking at my answer, I would suppose you are correct. I'd have to dig back into it to know for sure though. My guess is that its an HTML specific optimization of the expectation of the spec since most browsers move into SVG mode after hitting the first SVG element in an HTML document.

Comment: i'm just trying to understand why it's so important for the root svg not to overflow. i've seen this `not(:root)` on several different websites, but have yet to understand why the root svg should hide its overflow. I'm starting to think there is no reason.

Comment: I believe the spec regarding this was born out of how it would work if embedded via `object` `img` and other html tags.  Trying to ensure consistency between embedding options. Of course, this is just a guess and, regardless, it was what the spec says is required :)