# Overflow: Visible on SVG

Tags: css, svg, webkit, overflow

Is it possible set `overflow: visible` on `<svg>` elements?

[This simple example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nu5m6/) breaks in every browser I have access to, (some versions of Chrome and Firefox) as they act like `overflow: hidden`.

Can anybody tell me if svg support is simply still too immature to do such simple things, or if I'm doing something wrong in my code?

My practical use of `overflow: visible` is a range-axis on a graph, where the bottom half of the `-0` tick gets cut off.

Comment: Looks like not. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/10077264/165673

Comment: now above example works (at least at 53 google chrome)

Comment: `overflow: visible` works on at least Safari 10 iOS.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I assume you mean inline <svg> elements in HTML, if so then this is just an implementation limitation. IE9+ allows `overflow:visible` on <svg> elements, but so far the other browsers don't AFAIK.

One possible workaround (which is really how it should be done in the first place IMHO) is to specify a `viewBox` which defines the coordinate system inside the svg. Then you draw stuff inside this coordinate system. If things get clipped (or in other words if the element(s) are outside the `viewBox` area), then just increase the `viewBox` width and/or height accordingly.

If you wonder about a good default for your particular `viewBox`, try `[0 0 width height]` (where width and height is the size of your svg you have at the moment), then just increase the height until the bottom tick is fully visible.

**2014 update:** 
It's still a little bit inconsistent across browsers, but it's getting there. Firefox and IE support `overflow:visible` on inline svg elements, and Blink (Opera 23/Chrome 36) added support for it too, for the details see [bugreport](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=231577).

Comment: If I set a viewBox my svg-elements are scaled to fit inside the main svg element. They still don't overflow. Just making the svg bigger to fit the stuff I want to overflow, will break the html layout.

Comment: Maybe what I really needed to know is whether webkit supports this, if the standard specifies it, and if I'm right that webkit used to support it?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. No you're going to have to workaround the lack of support for `overflow:visible` by increasing the viewport (aka the size of the svg).

Comment: awesome. just like magic. solved most of the bugs I was trying to resolve.

Comment: I'm wanting `overflow:hidden` so that the SVG is not visible outside its container. Can we do that?

Answer (score 6):

```
overflow: visible  
box-shadow : 0px -0px 10000px transparent /*trick for chrome*/
```

Adding a huge box-shadow to the SVG , or adding the SVG  in a DIV with the huge shadow solve it. In Chrome I noticed that the overflow is being clipped to the box-shadow limit.