# SVG overflow visible in chrome but behind elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm trying to use the property `overflow: visible` on SVG.

It's displaying well but there is an issue :
When I try to put an event on the element that is out of the SVG, it doesn't work. It's like the svg element is behind the other elements.
I've tried to play with `z-index` but it doesn't work.
I would rather prefer to don't use the `viewBox` in that answer [Overflow: Visible on SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326838/overflow-visible-on-svg).

Here is the code :

HTML

```
<p>Blabla</p>

<svg width="100" height='100'>
    <circle id='c1' cx='10px' cy='-10px' r='5' onclick='alert("c1")'></circle>
    <circle id='c2' cx='10px' cy='10px' r='5' onclick='alert("c2")'></circle>
</svg>
```

CSS

```
svg {
    overflow: visible;
}

circle {
    fill: black;
}

circle:hover {
    fill: red;
}
```

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9r78K/3/)

When I click on the first circle that overflows the SVG it's not displaying the alert. But for the one, that is inside the SVG it works.

The problem appears to be only in Chrome. On Firefox and IE it's working.

Comment: Sorry for that. Just edited it with the code.

Comment: No worries, thanks for fixing that. I've filed a Blink bug for this, http://crbug.com/401443, and I'll have a fix in review shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 for the question.. A strange behaviour.. and as far I googled about the issue..
I got this:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=96163

and for chrome:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=231577

So I think it is an issue.. waiting for other solutions too.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, sorry for my english skill.

You are right, when you create

```
<circle id='c1' cx='10' cy='-10' r='5' onclick='alert("click");'></circle>
```

It's `cy='-10'`moves your `circle#c1` under the `<p>` -10px to top

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/9r78K/31/

I hope I correctly understood your problem.

Comment: Thanks! So I didn't play right with the `z-index property`

Comment: You are welcome, if you want to learn more about z-index: [read this](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)

Comment: Sorry not working. I thought that it was right when I tried your fiddle. But, I want the `circle#c1` to be above the `<p>`and that it works as well. More like this : http://jsfiddle.net/9r78K/32/