# SVG Container issue in internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, d3.js

I am implementing the network topology using D3js library which uses SVG for graphics rendering.I am using the force layout to implement the same.

I am using this example  http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708.
When we see this example in new window by clicking open in anew window http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/6123708/,it bahevious perfactly with respect to container in Google-chrome and Firefox but not in Internet explorer (IE version is 11).

Google-chrome Screen
[image]

IE Screen
[image]

You can compare that in google chrome when move the grid lines with dots it moves with respect to its container while in IE it doesn't,It consider whole body as the container.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077264/should-svg-contents-be-visible-outside-an-embedded-svg-by-default

Comment: dear Erik focus on sollution rather than duplicate data.:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVG image is not cropped in IE9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971320/svg-image-is-not-cropped-in-ie9)

Comment: The solution has been provided more than once before... in those other questions :)

Comment: Obviously but this solution works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<svg width="960" height="500" viewBox="0 0 960 500" style="overflow:hidden;">
```